# how to unfold a let expression inside a theorem?

Tags: lean

I'm trying to prove a theorem, and to do so I have to prove a lemma about a function I define during the proof. The issue is that I would like to unfold the definition of the function, but I get an error when I try to use the `delta` or `unfold` tactics.
I've reproduced the issue in this snippet:

```
example : True := by
  let F : ℕ→ℕ := λ _ => 0
  have F_le_1 : ∀(n:ℕ), F n ≤ 1 := by
    intro n
    delta F
```

At this point, I get the error `unknown constant '_root_.F'`.

What am I missing?

(I should add that I don't get the same error if I define the function outside of the theorem, but I would prefer to know what I'm overlooking, rather than just patching up the problem).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `show` statements instead:

```
example : 0 ≤ 1 :=
  let F : Nat → Nat := λ _ => 0
  have F_le_1 (n : Nat) : F n ≤ 1 := by
    show (λ _ => 0) n ≤ 1
    exact Nat.zero_le 1
  F_le_1 1

example : let F : Nat → Nat := λ _ => 0; ∀ (n : Nat), F n ≤ 1 := by
  show ∀ (n : Nat), (λ _ => 0) n ≤ 1
  intro _
  exact Nat.zero_le 1
```

In fact, you can prove these propositions without `show` statements.

```
example : 0 ≤ 1 :=
  let F : Nat → Nat := λ _ => 0
  have F_le_1 (n : Nat) : F n ≤ 1 := Nat.zero_le 1
  F_le_1 1

example : let F : Nat → Nat := λ _ => 0; ∀ (n : Nat), F n ≤ 1 := by
  intro _F _n
  exact Nat.zero_le 1
```

Comment: I can't get this to work for more complicated functions, isn't there a way to perform this substitution without manually rewriting the body of the function?

Comment: @sortai Please visit [the Lean chat at Zulip](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/) and ask about your functions there. You may not even need to use `show` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Mathlib has a tactic called `unfold_let` specifically for unfolding local definitions.

```
example : True := by
  let F : ℕ→ℕ := λ _ => 0
  have F_le_1 : ∀(n:ℕ), F n ≤ 1 := by
    intro n
    unfold_let F
    /-
    F: ℕ → ℕ := fun x ↦ 0
    n: ℕ
    ⊢ (fun x ↦ 0) n ≤ 1
    -/
```

In a recent version of Lean 4, now `simp` and `dsimp` can take local variables as arguments to specify that they should be unfolded.

```
example : True := by
  let F : ℕ→ℕ := λ _ => 0
  have F_le_1 : ∀(n:ℕ), F n ≤ 1 := by
    intro n
    dsimp only [F]
    /-
    F: ℕ → ℕ := fun x ↦ 0
    n: ℕ
    ⊢ 0 ≤ 1
    -/
```

(Note: if you are on a slightly older Lean 4 version, you might be able to get by with just `dsimp only []` because it does zeta substitution by default.)